# Problema com JSON - Python3.4

Tags: json, api, python-3.x, binary

Estou trabalhando com a API do BuscaPé para poder retirar informações de alguns produtos do site, o problema é que não consigo manipular um dos valores do json retornado. Abaixo segue alguns resultados que consegui obter:

```
resp = buscape.find_product_list(keyword='jogos', format='json') # Fazendo a consulta

resp.keys() # Retornou: 'dict_keys(['data', 'code'])'

type(resp['code']) # Retornou: '<\class 'int>'

type(resp['data']) # Retornou: '<\class 'bytes>'
```

Como vocês podem ver, quando eu verifiquei o tipo do resp['data'] (campo que detêm os valores que preciso) o python me retornou o valor "class bytes", com isso, até consigo converter esse valor para string, o problema é que seria trabalhoso procurar cada informação que preciso dessa forma .

Já tentei fazer o dump da seguinte forma:

```
import json

json.dumps(resp)
```

Mas o intepretador me retorna o seguinte erro: **is not JSON serializable**.

[Como o json é muito grande, deixei o código hospedado no meu pastebin para vocês terem uma noção melhor do problema que estou enfrentando.](http://pastebin.com/EsYJ75UB)

Comment: Galera, consegui resolver o problema, só precisei fazer o decode('utf-8') do campo resp['data'], assim consegui fazer o json.loads e manipular as informações que eu precisava.

Comment: André, coloque a sua resposta aqui embaixo(seção de respostas) para caso alguém queira saber também sobre este problema!

Comment: Resolveu sua duvida?

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que consegui entender, basta você utilizar o método **.decode** para converter de bytes para unicode. Veja se consegue fazer essa conversão da seguinte maneira:

```
import json

json.dumps(resp['data'].decode('utf-8'))
```